# I want to add a csv file content into the database and it's not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I want the admin of the website to select a CSV file with a file input. The CSV file with have users in it which is then inserted into the database with randomly generated passwords. For each user inserted into the database, the user will receive a mail which contains their login (which is their email) and their password.

I tried to get the CSV content in an array with a library but I haven't managed to make it work.

Here is the function in the controller that reads the CSV file

```
public function lire_csv()
    {
         $this->load->library('Csvimport');
         $file_data = $this->Csvimport->get_array($_FILES["csv_file"]["liste_etu"]);
         foreach($file_data as $row)
         {
             $data[] = array(

                'nom' => $row["Nom"],
                'prenom' => $row["Prenom"],
                'statut'=> "Etudiant",
                'civilite' => $row["Civilite"],             
                'mail' => $row["Email"],
                'adresse' => $row["Adresse"],
                'complement' => $row["Complement"],
                'code_postal' => $row["Code_postal"],
                'ville' => $row["Ville"],
                'pays' =>$row["Pays"],
                'tel' => $row["Telephone"],
                'date_naiss' => $row["Date_de_naissance"],
                'num_secu' => $row["Numero_secu"],
                'mutuelle' => $row["Mutuelle"],
                'objectif_pro' => $row["Objectif_pro"],
                'motdepasse' => uniqid()    
             );
             $this->envoyer_mail($data['mail'],$data['motdepasse'],$data['nom'],$data['prenom']);
         }
         $this->mStages->create_utilisateur($data);

    }
```

This is the library I used [CSV Import](https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import/blob/master/libraries/csvimport.php)

This function gives me warning about the timeset

And finally here is the view code portion where the admin has to select the CSV file. There is a weird behavior because only the rectangle surrounding the button that is supposed to open the file explorer works, but the button itself does nothing.

```
<form action=<?php echo base_url('index.php/main_stage/lire_csv'); ?> method="post">

                 <center><input type="file" name="fichier" id="csv_file" required accept=".csv"/></center> <p>Fichier .csv uniquement</p>

                 <input type="submit" value="Envoyer la liste">
```

When I try to send the CSV I get these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Main_stage::$Csvimport

Filename: controllers/main_stage.php

Line Number: 507

Backtrace:

File: D:\boulot\php\UwAmp\www\Projet_PHP\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\controllers\main_stage.php
Line: 507
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\boulot\php\UwAmp\www\Projet_PHP\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function get_array() on null in      D:\boulot\php\UwAmp\www\Projet_PHP\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\controllers\main_stage.php on line 507
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0149  150416  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0281  197248  require_once( 'D:\boulot\php\UwAmp\www\Projet_PHP\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' )  ...\index.php:315
3   0.3565  2069632 call_user_func_array:{D:\boulot\php\UwAmp\www\Projet_PHP\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:532} ( ) ...\CodeIgniter.php:532
4   0.3565  2069832 Main_stage->lire_csv( ) ...\CodeIgniter.php:532
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function get_array() on null

Filename: controllers/main_stage.php

Line Number: 507

Backtrace:
```

I want to see how can I improve my code or easier ways to do this.

Comment: there is a pretty important section in the docs - _Once loaded you can access your class using the lower case version_ - take a look here - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#using-your-class - which means instead of `$this->Csvimport` use `$this->csvimport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me i don't use third-party libraries for dealing with relatively simple files like `csv` cause you can already read it in one line of code and convert it you an array like this:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('book.csv'));
```

Then we will create an array of associative arrays with the first row column headers as the keys like this:

```
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});
```

You can then remove column header and keep it if you want like this:

```
$header = array_shift($csv);
```

Then you can add your random password to each user like this:

```
foreach ($csv as $key => $value) 
{
    $csv[$key]['password'] = 'random_password';
}
```

This will generate an array like this:

```
[0]=>
array(3) {
    ["username"]=>
        string(6) "sherif"
    ["email"]=>
        string(15) "sherif@code.com"
    ["password"]=>
        string(15) "random_password"
}
...
```

Then continue doing your magic, send email to every single user in this array, save it to your db using `insert_batch` or whatever you wanna do.

Finally about your other `html/css` question, try asking another separate question.

---

**Final version:**

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('book.csv'));

array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});

$header = array_shift($csv);

foreach ($csv as $key => $value) 
{
    $csv[$key]['password'] = 'random_password';
}
```

---

**EDIT:** if you want to read the uploaded file you got two option, first is to read it directly form tmp like this:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']));
```

Or you can save the file first and read the path as mentioned before.

About if it would work with any `csv` file, yeah it should work with any valid csv file without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a solution I try this but I have a question in the function file('book.csv') you put the path of the csv file ?  because I want to put the path of the file the admin selected

Comment: Also if I understood well the array I get corresponds to the csv file rows so it works for any csv file ?

Comment: @Misteronsépatro .. don't worry, it will work i've **tested** it myself.

Comment: I tried with the file but I get an error which is                                                 Undefined index: uploadedfile

Comment: I wanted to do like you said reading the file directly but I don't understand those errors

Comment: @Misteronsépatro .. bro, you have to change the index with your file input name from the view, i just used `uploadedfile` as a placeholder .. i assumed that you will do that not copy the code exactly as it is! .. your input name is `fichier`.

Comment: It worked there is no more error I can handle the email sending and insertion into the database Thanks for the solution

Comment: @Misteronsépatro .. Glad it worked bro :) .. consider closing the question.